# Download DevOps 2019 migration tools

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We have an on premise DevOps 2019 update 1.2 (17.153.32407.5) that we want to migrate to Azure DevOps (cloud) but we can’t find the data migration tools for 2019.
The tools posted here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274 or here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops  are only for DevOps 2020 update 1 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, data migration tool only supports Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.2 and 2020.1.1. The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time.

**If you are using Azure DevOps Server 2019, you need to upgrade to 2020 firstly.** Please refer to [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2022) for detailed information.

Please select the version you want to upgrade to carefully when upgrading. The data migration tool doesn't support imports from Azure DevOps Server release candidates (RC) and it can take up to 2-3 weeks after a new RTW version of Azure DevOps Server is released for import support to come online for that version.